# How do I change iTerm2's visual bell to just a flashing screen?

Tags: terminal, gui, iterm2

I know I have seen this set on other computers, but I'm uncertain how to change this myself.

Also, I've tried changing bell.png in: ~/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/bell.png

However, I'd like to avoid this hack, if this setting can be enabled some other way.

It seems trivial in terminal.app (Preferences->Settings->Advanced->Visual Bell); this flashes the screen in exactly the way I'd like. I just want to do this for iTerm2 instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option has been included since version 3.0.0, and can be found at `Preferences > Advanced > Terminal: Visual bell flashes the whole screen, not just a bell icon`.